# React functional component - test an element instanceOf baseElement

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

In old way react component (class based component),
it's easy to determine the specified child/element is the kind of the baseComponent.
Something like this:

```
class CatComponent extends React.Component { /* ... */ }

class LionComponent extends CatComponent { /* ... */ }

/* ... */
<FooComponent>
{(Array.isArray(props.children) ? props.children : [props.children]).map((child, index) => {
   if (React.isValidElement(child) && (child.type.prototype instanceof CatComponent || child.type===CatComponent)) {
      return doSomething(child);
   }
   else {
      return doAnother(child);
   }
})}
</FooComponent>
/* ... */
```

The question is, how about **functional components** like this:

```
function CatComponent() { /* ... */ }

function LionComponent() { return <CatComponent>
   <AnotherComp>
   </AnotherComp>
</CatComponent> }
```

Is there a way to determine the `LionComponent` is the kind of `CatComponent`?

The `child.type` point to the `LionComponent` but i've no idea to determine the `LionComponent` is kind of `CatComponent`.